# SQL Server 2008 Project Convertion Disables T-SQL Code Recognition in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2010

I created a sql server 2008 database project.  When I edit the default Script.PostDeployment.sql (or any .sql) script then my Transact-SQL Editor toolbar in VS is highlighted and active, and I have no compile errors.  When I right-click the project and click "Convert to SQL Server Database project", I start getting errors and my Transact-SQL Editor is no longer highlighted/active.  An error I get, for example is in the Script.PostDeployment.sql, where it says the :r .\myscript.sql command is invalid because :r is not a valid syntax.  This is a new project (although, I tried to import a database with the toolbar also not recognizing any of the table .sql files).  What step am I missing so that after the conversion it recognizes the .sql file as legitimate transact-sql with an active T-SQL Editor toolbar?

My current method is this:  With SQL 2008 R2, in Visual Studio 2010 w/ latest SP I do this:

- Create SQL Server 2008 Database Project
- Add Post-Deployment file
- Add Post-Deployment reference line
- Compile, and it tests ok
- Convert to SQL Server Database project via right-click
- Syntax errors now happen; T-SQL Editor toolbar is greyed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the conversion changes the default editor for .sql files from "Transact-SQL Editor" to "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Database Projects, Editor Selector".  To fix, right-click on a .sql files in the project.  Go to "Open with..." and set the default editor back to "Transact-SQL Editor".  Now all the files will open properly and the syntax error will go away and the toolbar is active.